# How to use tsconfig.json file in Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, tsconfig

I have a NodeJS project using TypeScript, currently opened as a existing Node project.

On the project properties I can see a tab to configure TypeScript, but instead of using the proj file I would like to use tsconfig.json so people using Atom could also build with the same settings.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to use tsconfig.json instead of the proj file?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 uses tsconfig.json by default. But AFAIK there is not GUI to change settings, instead you can edit the file in VS - it is just JSON.

Also code completion works for settings in JSON schema - http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig (this works maybe thanks to some plugin I have installed - not sure).